# How to add Preference Activity to Language & keyboard?

Tags: android, android-input-method

I create my keyboard (based on google Soft Keyboard)
How to add activity with keyboard preferences to language & keyboard settings?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should put a xml file at res/xml/method.xml like following;

```
<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:settingsActivity="your.package.YourPreferenceActivity"
              android:name="@string/your_app_name" />
```

(o´∀`o)ﾉ .•*¨*•.¸¸♬