# Android: How to create system preferences screen for InputMethodService

Tags: sharedpreferences, android-softkeyboard, preferenceactivity, android-input-method, android-settings

I'm building a soft keyboard, and I can't figure out how to properly build a preferences screen that shows up in the system settings.

I've built the elements screen in xml (preferences.xml), I've populated the options (just a simple ListPreference to select the desired language).  That's all fine.

When launching the keyboard (View onCreate InputView()...) I've set things up to write the default preferences to shared preferences:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getBaseContext(), R.xml.preferences, true);

SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

I've also set up a shared preferences listener to determine whether any changes are made to the preferences so I can update the dictionary:

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                // do stuff
            }
        };
SP.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

All of this seems to be fine.  But I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the preferences screen to show up in the system settings (Settings -> Language and Input -> Keyboard and Input Preferences) so I can actually CHANGE anything.  All the other keyboards have a slot here that open up into preference screens where settings can be adjusted.  My keyboard name has its own slot, but nothing happens if I touch it.  How do I get my preferences screen to be accessible through here?

Comment: Okay, turns out the shared preferences listener is NOT fine.  It seems to be a case of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently) but not sure how to fix that either.

Comment: For me the answer here worked worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839400/how-to-add-preference-activity-to-language-keyboard

Comment: Worked!  Can't thank you enough.